# Bug: excess searches message shows advanced search options instead

Tags: bug, search

There is a little-known rate-limiter in Stack Overflow search that kicks in, I think, around 30 searches per 60 second window. I bump into it every now and again, as I use search heavily to find posts that need editing.

As of a few weeks ago, the "too many searches" error no longer shows, and instead the advanced search help is shown:

[image: Advanced search help table]

So, the trigger is probably by design, but the display is not.

This does not look like it can be replicated by searching for the same word 30 times - I suspect some caching is wrapped around search, so this won't trigger it. But "Hello 1", "Hello 2", etc does trigger it (I get to "Hello 31" when it kicks in, but it depends on how quickly one can do these tests).

Comment: As a note, I believe the advanced search help is shown by default if you click on the search bar and hit Enter while it's empty (i.e. you haven't typed anything in it).

Comment: Interesting @V2Blast - I don't think I've noticed that before - perhaps that is a deliberate feature, and is causing an interaction effect. But the search queries in this case are all non-empty.

Comment: I can reproduce this. The "too many searches" error message displays not only when you're rate-limited, but also when the site is in the middle of a redeploy. Now, instead of that message, I also see the advanced search help.

Comment: Interesting - I think there has been a search upgrade in the last day or so. The excess searches device has disappeared (I can't get it to trigger even with heavy manual search usage) and some search terms are now finding significantly more results than they were before (perhaps the word stemmer algorithm has been adjusted).

Comment: Ah, I have just triggered the search limiter - but it seems it is set much higher than before. Maybe 100 searches in five minutes.