# Has the search system been recently upgraded?

Tags: bug, search

In the last day or so, search behaviour has changed a fair bit. I'm marking this question as a bug report, but it may just be a bug enquiry—i.e. I'm reporting the fix and not the bug!

I reported a bug recently [about a wonky search limiter display](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423272/bug-excess-searches-message-shows-advanced-search-options-instead). I wonder if that caused SE engineers to improve this module. If so, thank you!

Now the overuse limits are much more generous (which is great for editors who use search to find improvable content). I also note that for specific searches, the numbers of returned results have grown significantly. I am minded to think that the parsing or stemming of specific words ("thanks" and "help" particularly) has been improved (i.e. before the change, some search results were missing—at a guess, possibly older material before 2015).

Can an engineer shed any light on what change has been made? Am I right to suspect the rate-limit has been increased, and shall that be permanent? (If this is temporary I wonder if it could be raised for editors, or maybe a higher limit could be linked to reputation.)